# Probability of recurrence of the same two numbers in two consecutive lottery drawings

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given lottery game 6 out of 49, I would like to know how high the probability of recurrence of the same two numbers (i.e. 6 and 12) in two consecutive lottery drawings is. In this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lottery_mathematics) I read that the probability of scoring two numbers in this lottery game is about `0.132`.

My questions are:

1. What is the probability of recurrence of the same two numbers (i.e. 6 and 12) in two consecutive lottery drawings?
2. How would I calculate if this recurrence of the two numbers provides evidence for lottery fraud?

Comment: Could you please clarify the event in question?  Are you going to specify the two numbers (a) before both lotteries, (b) after the first, or (c) after both?  If it's after both, presumably you're asking whether *some* pair of numbers might recur.  Would that include the cases where three, four, five, or all six numbers recur?  If it's after the first, are you going to look for recurrence of any pair of the six chosen numbers or of a specific pair?

Comment: After both. Hm, exactly two numbers. But at least two numbers also is an interesting question. That would include more extreme events. I look for the probability of the consecutive recurrence of any pair of numbers.

Comment: It would help to include that information in the question.  It might also help you obtain an answer yourself by rephrasing it as the event in which, in the second lottery, two numbers are drawn from the six previously drawn and four are drawn from the remaining 43.  A moment's reflection will indicate these are independent events and so their probabilities (which are easily computed) multiply to give the answer. This gives a [hypergeometric probability](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=hypergeometric+distribution+-multivariate+score%3A2+subset).